# iptables script breaking internet connection

Tags: networking, server, vpn, iptables, firewall

Looking for some help in where I'm going wrong with an `iptables` script I've been using for a long time.

I was using this on Ubuntu Server 16.04 without any problems, I've upgraded to 19.04 (yes it's a fresh install) and suddenly I have issues I can't seem to overcome..

The script is:

```
*filter    
:INPUT DROP
:FORWARD DROP
:OUTPUT DROP
-A INPUT -s 192.168.1.1/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 192.168.1.1/24 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d *VPN IP here* -p udp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s *VPN IP Here* -p udp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i tun0 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

Without these rules in `iptables`, the VPN works perfectly on 19.04.
As soon as I commit these rules to `iptables`, the internet shuts off as such, I can't get a ip readback from `curl ipecho.net/plain`, it just says...

> can't resolve hostname

...yet however I can ping google (8.8.8.8) and it pings fine.
I can't even get any update list from ubuntu with `apt-get update`.

I've checked that the adapter names are correct and the VPN is `tun0`, so it's not that.

The script is designed to kill the internet if something happens to the VPN connection (network cable unplugged, router reset etc downtime on the VPN server), however the VPN works and is connected so I'm not sure why it won't work as intended.

As I say it worked perfectly on 16.04 however wont on 19.04. Confused.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Does 19.04 use systemd-resolved? if so, what loopback address is it listening on (it won't necessarily be127.0.0.1 I think)? maybe you need to allow that as well?

Comment: Thank you! I googled systemd-resolved and it gave me a loopback IP of 127.0.0.53, and the location to verify it, so I did that, added it to the script and it works perfectly. Thank you so much!

Comment: @D4T4 Would you be able to edit in/post what the change to the script was that allowed `127.0.0.53 (:53)` to be accessed through IP Tables so that anyone looking for that (which is what led me here) can update their scripts?

Answer (score 1):

The message `can't resolve hostname` suggests the problem is one of name resolution.

On recent versions of Ubuntu, DNS operates via a local caching server that listens on port 53 on a suitable loobpack address - however, the specific address is not the canonical `127.0.0.1` that you have already allowed.

For instance, 16.04 systems use `dnsmasq` on `127.0.1.1` by default

```
$ sudo netstat -nlp | grep LISTEN | grep :53
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1020/dnsmasq
```

whereas 18.04 uses `systemd-resolved` on 127.0.0.53

```
$ sudo netstat -nlp | grep LISTEN | grep :53
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3677/systemd-resolv
```

In order for DNS queries to resolve, you will need to allow inbound connections on the corresponding address (although you may limit these to the specific port, `53`).